# php regex solution for instances of string in string

Tags: php, regex

I have this string in php:

```
$variable = 'Default: 7" W x 4" H • Option Late: 1 ½" W x 3/16" H, Up Charge: $50.00 plus .50 per piece. '
```

The first part before the `:` could be anything

I will be using

```
$regex=?
preg_match($regex, $variable, $matches)
```

What should $regex be in order for the $matches array to contain `7" W x 4" H` & `1 ½" W x 3/16" H`

There is no particular pattern this string could be in. The parts that I need will always be in the format in previous line.

Comment: could you explain your question a bit more? Why you don't want to match the value of `Charge` ?

Comment: What is the separator between single key-value pairs? Is it the middle dot `·` or a comma `,`. If you can find a regular pattern like this you may split the string using `explode` on those characters instead of trying to find a regexp.

Comment: I only need the dimensions, they will always be a number" W x number" H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in `preg_match_all`:

```
(\b\d.*? *H\b)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hD0sL3/3)

This will give you 2 matches:

1. `7" W x 4" H`
2. `1 ½" W x 3/16" H`